# How to position a TextView inside a RelativeLayout from another RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am having this problem where I need to place TextView(green) inside RelativeLayout(blue) below RelativeLayout(black) but ImageView(orange) stays overlapping

[image]

Here's the legend:

- RelativeLayout(black) id/image_view_container
- ImageView(brown)
- RelativeLayout(blue)
- ImageView(orange) id/profileImage
- TextView(green)

I tried:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profileImage"
android:layout_below="@id/image_view_container"
```

but it's not working, probably because `image_view_container` is from another RelativeLayout.

I need assistance in this, thanks ahead!

Edit:

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image_view_container" >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/mainImage"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="210dp" 
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    />
    </RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profileImage"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/image_view_container"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profileImage"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="6363"
                android:textColor="@color/A"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:translationY="5dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post complete xml pls, seems like your blue relative layout container is not proper

Comment: How are you including _the other_ layout?

Comment: pls post the your whole XML file...

Comment: Blue is only required if it has a background, even then, green and orange don't need to be in it (can be in the same RelativeLayout as black)

Comment: I was trying to do it through two RelativeLayouts but no luck. thanks to this! I haven't thought of it 'til now. I could encapsulate the orange and green under the same RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your `image_view_container`

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/image_view_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff00ff" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="310dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="#ffff00" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image_view_container"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="#ff1234"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/profileImage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profileImage"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="6363"
        android:background="#ff0034"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```